# How to load multiple files(*.xml) via XmlDocument C#

Tags: c#

I wanted to load multiple *.xml* files in C#. Currently, I am able to load only 1 *.xml* file.
But not able to find out how will be able to load multiple files .

My code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
string path = @"path of *.xml file";  //
doc.Load(path);
```

Comment: Do you mean multiple xml files into one `XmlDocument` instance? I doubt that's possible because `XmlDocument` has a notion of a `root` element which is ill-defined if you concatenate two xml trees (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.documentelement.aspx). You can just create another instance of `XmlDocument`. If you really want them to be in the same `XmlDocument` instance, you can consider wrapping all of xml trees under your own root node...

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems? I think you just need to load it into separate XmlDocument objects.

Comment: I think this 3 previous questions have your solution :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078067/how-do-i-load-multiple-xml-files-and-read-them
 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015902/loading-multiple-xml-documents-from-folder
 -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15002428/loading-multiple-xml-files-with-c-sharp-xmldocument-leading-to-memory-leakage

Comment: What would you use all the documents for? Why do you need to have them all available at once?

Comment: @Alex Filipovici: All the xml files are config files and i need to change the values in all these files. Same value need s to be changed in all these files. If i change value one file at a time, my code becomes very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't have to bee *too* big, you just need to store all the paths in some collection, then you have to apply the same operation to each XML file.

```
string newValue = "1234";
XmlDocument doc;
var paths = new[] { "config1.xml", "config2.xml" };
paths.ToList().ForEach(path =>
{
    doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);

    // process the document
    var nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    var a = doc.SelectSingleNode("//SomeKeyValue", nm);
    a.InnerText = newValue;

    // save the file
    doc.Save(path);
});
```